# Why doesn't work the calling to a method in JAVA (Single example)

Tags: java, methods

I'm working with LeapMotion. I have this code in my main class:

```
public void onFrame(Controller controller) {
    Frame frame = controller.frame();
    GestoPistola gesto;

    if (!frame.hands().isEmpty()) 
    {
        System.out.println("ENTER");
        gesto.reconocer(frame);
    }
…
}
```

And then, this is the class GestoPistola, which is the one that has to make all the job.

```
    public class GestoPistola {
       public enum ESTADO{
           DESCARGADA, CARGADA
       }

       ESTADO _estado;

       public void GestoPistola(){
           _estado = ESTADO.DESCARGADA;
       }

       public void reconocer(Frame f)
       {
           System.out.println("LET'S START");

           if (!f.hands().isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println("Hay mano");
               Hand hand = f.hands().get(0);
               FingerList fingers = hand.fingers();

               switch(_estado)
               {
                     …
               }
           }
        }
   }
```

So, the consol shows "ENTER", but never "LET'START".

I know it's a really simple question, but I'm not such an expert with JAVA.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: You probably have a Null Pointer Exception in the line `gesto.reconocer(frame);`, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize `gesto`, so you probably get a `NullPointerException` when you attempt to call `reconocer`.

Change

```
GestoPistola gesto;
```

to

```
GestoPistola gesto = new GestoPistola ();
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize your gesto variable, so there's a NullPointerException.

Change `GestoPistola gesto;` to `GestoPistola gesto = new GestoPistola();`